# Handling polymer elements with different heights inside <core-pages>

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have a `<core-drawer-panel>` and inside it is a `<core-pages>` element inside `<core-header-panel main>`.

`<core-pages>` contains a set of custom elements that I have defined and only one of those elements are shown at any point of time. However the problem is, there are elements that take only part of the screen but still scroll vertically. The amount of scrolling is equal to the tallest element within `<core-pages>`.

The expected behavior is that the element should scroll only if it exceeds it's view port. How can I achieve this behavior?

**demo-students.html** (Stripped down version, to make it more readable)

```
<polymer-element name="students-dashboard">
  <template>
    <style>
      …
    </style>

    <core-drawer-panel…>
      <core-header-panel drawer mode="seamed">
          …
      </core-header-panel>

      <core-header-panel main mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar …>
          <span flex>Students</span>
        </core-toolbar>

        <div class="content">
          <core-pages selected={{getModule(route)}} valueattr="name">
            <!--
              This needs to scroll and it does
            -->
            <students-grid name="students"></students-grid>

            <!--
              The content of this element is short,
              but still scrolls to the same extent as the
              <students-grid> element
            -->
            <student-editor name="student_editor"></students-editor>
          </core-pages>
        </div>
      <core-header-panel>
    </core-drawer-panel>
  </template>

  <script>
    …
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Please provide a jsbin and code snippet of what you've tried.

Comment: @ebidel, I've included my code snippet. Please check it out.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the same issue I had: when using `<core-pages>` it was scrolling **beyond** the content of the smaller tabs. Each pages had the same size as the biggest page.

Nothing worked except replacing `<core-pages>` with `<animated-core-pages>` which made the problem magically disappear.

I had a similar problem with `<core-scaffold>` from the starter project which was different from the version downloaded by bowser (the same day). A bug disappeared when using the latter.

Tldr: Maybe the starter project is not up-to-date.

PS: this fixed the pages size problem not the fact that the scroll position is keeped across pages.

Comment: this did the trick for me too. Fortunately I had planned on moving to core-animated-pages at some point anyway but spent a few hours pulling my hair out till I found this answer.
Given that you can use core-animated-pages the same as core-pages I'm not sure there is any point in having both

Comment: Unfortunately, I fooled myself. This does not work for me after all :-(

Comment: Changing to core-animated-pages fixes the problem for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar struggle but with `<core-animated-pages>` inside a `<core-header-panel>` inside a `<core-drawer-panel>`.

I ended up getting the internal page element to fit and scroll itself by doing the following.

On the main page's css:

```
core-drawer-panel, core-header-panel {
    height: 100%;
}

core-animated-pages {    << core-pages for your example
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    flex: 1;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

On the polymer element's css:

```
:host {
    display: block;
    flex: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Give it a go and let us know how it works.

Comment: Hi, I added main pages's CSS to index.html and polymer element's CSS to <demo-students>, I don't see any changes here. Also I've read that the CSS properties in Polymer don't bleed in/out, unless explicitly specified. I've also tried doing the reverse main pages's CSS into <demo-students> and polymer's CSS in main page. But there's no change in behavior. PS: This is my first time building a web application I'm building a web application (I'm a mobile developer).