# How to use core-scroll-header-panel with core-animated-pages

Tags: polymer, core-elements

Following up from [How to use core-scroll-header-panel with core-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824034/how-to-use-core-scroll-header-panel-with-core-list) I want place the `core-list` inside a `core-animated-pages`

I modified the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cahona/2/edit) that [Jeff Posnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385997/jeff-posnick) provided in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824034/how-to-use-core-scroll-header-panel-with-core-list#comment42302854_26848705) to add the `core-animated-pages`. See http://jsbin.com/xibile/1

Unfortunately, the `core-animated-pages` seems to ignore the size of it's children in determining it's own size. I can work around this by changing the overflow of `list-test` to `visible` instead of `hidden`. See http://jsbin.com/xibile/2 (note you need to resize the window before the list renders)

This works reasonably OK but seems like a hack. Before I introduced the `core-animated-pages` the content div gracefully grew to accommodate the size of its child (list-test). Now it doesn't and I simply bust out of it via overflow

How do I get `core-animated-pages` to size to the size of the currently selected child?

This seems to have been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644993/handling-polymer-elements-with-different-heights-inside-core-pages) but there was no satisfactory answer. I'm hoping this has changed in the latest version of core elements

Also if anyone knows how to fix it so that you don't have to resize the window to get the list to render that would be awesome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `.content` div, try wrapping the `list-test` with a `session` and you will have a scollable list again. Please see this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vufigipega/1/).

```
<div class="content">
  <core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="0">
    <session>
      <list-test id="list" data="{{data}}"></list-test>
    </session>
  </core-animated-pages>
</div>
```

Here is why.

Before you wrap the `list-test` with the `core-animated-pages`, the `.content` `div` has an `absolute` position (with a `padding-top` so it doesn't get covered up by the main heading of the `core-scroll-header-panel`) and that's [why](https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/47#issuecomment-63126241) your `list-test` was displaying correctly.

Now that you wrap it with a `core-animated-pages` which has a default `position` of `relative`, your list becomes collapsed.

The fix is easy, wrap your `list-test` with another `session`. You don't even need to make it `fit` as the `core-animated-pages` will automatically give its *direct* children the css below -

```
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

**Update**

For the `core-list` rendering bug, you might be able to get away from re-calling `updateSize()` after a short day (50ms), like this -

```
    t.addEventListener('template-bound', function () {
        var list = document.querySelector('list-test::shadow core-list');
        // to update the size
        list.updateSize();
        this.job('delay', function () {
            list.updateSize();
        }, 50);
```

Here's another [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wifota/1/) for this. Hopefully this issue will be addressed by the Polymer team in the future!

Comment: thanks Justin that does fix that problem. I still need to manually resize my window before the list displays (with your jsbin too). Is there a way to work around that too? Otherwise I'm going to have to do something dodgy in js on startup

Comment: Hi @Anders, I am not entirely sure why but if I run the code locally I do get some data coming back without the need of resizing the window.  One thing that I've noticed is that you are still using the old `platform.js` which is now replaced by `<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
  </script>`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: That's very strange. It seems to be a chrome only thing. I'm on chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) on mac os yosemite. I just tried firefox and safari and they both display 4 rows before window resize. 

All of them need window resizing to display all the rows though.

BTW I changed to webcomponents.js but same problem http://jsbin.com/miqafi/1

Comment: Hmm very interesting. Looks like if I call `coreList.updateSize();` then chrome shows up 4 rows but still I need to resize it to get everything. See this (http://jsbin.com/bubeki/1/).

Comment: must be some bug in core-list. I just set runwayFactor="100" and then firefox loads the full list up front http://jsbin.com/miqafi/4

Comment: and if I use your updateSize trick with the runwayFactor="100" chrome loads all up front too. Unfortunately this is very dependant on the size of the list

Comment: Yes, I tired that too but again if the list has more than 100 items, you still need to resize to show all... I think it's a bug.

Comment: Me too. I'll look for a bug and file if can't find one. Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at this post (https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/47#issuecomment-63126241). Keven said it's already fixed in version 5.2 but I am using 5.2 and this still doesn't seem to be fixed.

Comment: I think it might be https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/849 which is marked as fixed but not sure if it is released

Comment: I think it is. The updated code can be found here (https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/commit/86b8754d2014769a69890bff327152005d4c8606) and it looks identical to https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-list/core-list.html

Comment: hmmmm. Maybe the fix doesn't cover all scenarios

Comment: I'm assuming that if I pull straight from http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-list/core-list.html then I get that latest???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68120/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-anders).

Comment: I just tried [Justin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/231837/justin-xl)'s jsbin again and now it works on chrome. Doesn't work on chrome on the iphone though but still a progress of sorts